# Can grouped data be discrete?

Tags: statistics

**Context**

A frequency distribution is shown below

`Class interval | 1-20 | 21-40 | 41-60|`
`frequency      |  5   |  10   |   9  |`

Use interpolation to find an estimate for the interquartile range.

**My Working**

In order to answer this question I must first calculate the upper and lower quartiles.
In order to do that, I need to know if the data is continuous or discrete (formula for $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$).

**Question**

How can I tell if the data is discrete or continuous since the only information provided is 'Class interval' ?

***Therefore I am asking whether it is possible for grouped data to be discrete - or is it always continuous?***

REF: Statistics and Mechanics AS book

Comment: You can't tell.

Comment: There are separate formulae for quartiles in case of a grouped frequency distribution (this one), a simple frequency distribution and ungrouped data.

Comment: A clue that data may be integers (discrete) is that we have endpoints that preclude data between 20 and 21 or between 40 and 41. There are 24 observations, so the lower quartile must lie between 21 and 40 and and the upper quartile between 41 and 60 and you can't say for sure exactly where in either case. **However,** you are asked to use interpolation, presumably assuming data are "uniformly" spread within intervals. Then maybe Q1 is about 21 or 22 and Q3 about 1/3 of the way (left to right).  between 41 and 60. // Exact definitions of quartiles differ among texts. Try to use def'n in yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an attempt to find the IQR by simulation instead of
interpolation. So I am *not* saying I got the same answer you're
expected to get.

I simulated a million datasets with integer values at random, but
so that each dataset has the same intervals and frequencies as in your table.

I used R to apply its definition of quartiles (hence of IQRs) to find the
IQR of each of the million datasets, and averaged the million answers.
As you can see, I got IQR = 23.3. Maybe your answer from interpolation will be nearly the same.

```
set.seed(2020)
iqr = replicate(10^6, IQR(c(sample( 1:20,  5, rep=T),
                            sample(21:40, 10, rep=T),
                            sample(41:60,  9, rep=T))) )
mean(iqr)
[1] 23.31511
```

[image]

The first sample of the million:

```
set.seed(2020)
x = c(sample( 1:20,  5, rep=T),
      sample(21:40, 10, rep=T),
      sample(41:60,  9, rep=T))
x
 [1] 13  8 13 10  3 22 23 28 21 33 36 35 37 29 29
[16] 51 60 54 51 46 44 42 57 59

summary(x)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   3.00   21.75   34.00   33.50   47.25   60.00 

IQR(x)
[1] 25.5
```